# How to create bubble chat view in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, chat

I want to create bubble `chatView` like `WhatsApp` chat screen.

I am using below link to create bubble chat screen but I don't know how to use in `tableViewCell` when I add this `view` in `tableViewCell` then it adds again and again when I scroll.

How to resolve the issue? 
How to use `UIView` class in `tableViewCell`?

### https://www.innofied.com/creating-old-style-message-bubble-swift/

Comment: You can use this library for creating bubble chat - https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: without any 3rd party library

Comment: For that, you have to create custom table view cell, one for a sender and one for receiver and design that cell looks like the bubble.

Comment: yes, I have already created it but how to convert into chat bubble of tableview cell

Comment: For this reason, I told you to use the library and this library very easy to implement. Because programmatically you can create a bubble in your custom cell but that is very tricky and hard to design exactly look like the bubble.

Comment: please tell me how to design programmatically

Comment: Set background image which looks like a bubble to your sender & receiver cell base view and set the clear background color of cell view.